# UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions crashes silently without error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

SO I have a function which takes 2 images and combines them. Maybe the images are too large because when I try it with 2 smaller images it works fine but I am not sure. So I take a photo on my camera and try and open it from the album. I pick the Image and combine it with another image using this function:

```
- (UIImage*)imageByCombiningImage:(UIImage*)firstImage withImage:(UIImage*)secondImage {

    UIImage *image = nil;

    float scale = 0.5f;

    CGSize newImageSize = CGSizeMake(MAX(firstImage.size.width, secondImage.size.width), MAX(firstImage.size.height, secondImage.size.height));

        NSLog(@"reached image by combining image");
    //crashes here when the image has been selected from an album (secondImage).
    // runs fine when the image has been taken from the camera. (secondImage). 

    if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImageSize); 
    }



    [firstImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((newImageSize.width-firstImage.size.width)/2), 
                                        roundf((newImageSize.height-firstImage.size.height)/2))]; 

    UIImage *scaledImage = 
    [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[secondImage CGImage] 
                        scale:scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

    [scaledImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(roundf((100)), 
                                         roundf((100)))]; 
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

When I get to this line:

```
if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
} else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newImageSize); 
}
```

it crashes silently. I think it might be a memory problem? 
The method is also being called asynchronously.

Comment: Which line exactly does it crash at? the condition in the `if`? Either of the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext...` functions?

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newImageSize, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);  It then says "Received memory warning." in the console.

Comment: Just for future reference if you are using the lldb debugger then as soon as the crash happens you can type in the box on the right. Enter "bt" (for backtrace) and usually you can get more information about why the crash occurred

Comment: Ok I will remember that tahnkyou MobileMon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to decrease the size of the image by 3 before it stopped the crashing when merging. Just too big for it.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the solution to your question with only this info, but I would recommend you to check a couple of things:

1. You are in the main thread: Graphic primitives should only be called from that thread, and you said that it is called asynchronously. Check whether this async thread is the main one.
2. Remove unused code prior to posting: You are creating UIImageViews on the first lines that are not actually used. This is not only a waste of time/resources for your app, but also complicates the debugging and tracing the error in SO.

Comment: yes they are. I am using them to create a frame size for the images that were put in. I have trimmed down to code to my exact methodology before getting there.

Comment: In the coded posted you are not using them for anything. Assigning an image to a UIImageView and setting a frame does not change the original image or the one returned by the image property (will be the same one as the original). The first 7-8 lines are useless.

Comment: You are right. I updated my question with code that actually does things now.

Comment: Have you checked that you are in the main thread as suggested in point 1?

Comment: Then, I dont see the problem, as long as you are in the MainThread and you are passing a correct newImageSize the UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions should be working fine.

Comment: is it possible that the phone doesnt have enough memory to process the mergin of the two images? one image is taken from the camera, the other is a png.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same crash too, exactly!

From [UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions crashing](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/99027-uigraphicsbeginimagecontextwithoptions-crashing.html)

> Ok, UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions is a red herring. ......

It seems that the problem is xxx not being deallocated.

Comment: I had the same issue when defined a delegate under __unsafe_unretained, fixed it by changing to weak.